# Custom payload in APNS not delivered

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We are using APNS to send push notifications to out devices. The payload looks like the following:

```
{
    "data":{
        "aps":{
            "alert":{
                "loc-args":["bharathp"],
                "loc-key":"LiKudoAlertBody",
                "title-loc-key":"LiKudoAlertTitle"
            }
        },
        "fromName":"bharathp",
        "source":"community",
        "type":"kudos",
        "message":"{....some dictionary....}",
        "fromId":"1696757163"
    },
"to":"some string"
}
```

But on iOS when I receive the notification I only get the "aps" part of the payload.

```
[AnyHashable("aps"): {
alert =     {
    "loc-args" =         (
        bharathp
    );
    "loc-key" = LiKudoAlertBody;
    "title-loc-key" = LiKudoAlertTitle;
};
}]
```

I'm printing the above using

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        // Print notification payload data
        print("Push notification received: \(data)")
}
```

Is the format I'm sending incorrect? What could possibly be the issue here?

Comment: This is not a standard format for an APNS payload, are you using a 3rd party service to send your notifications?

Comment: It's not the standard format. Try something like this, {
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "title" : "Manish Kumar",
            "body" : "iOS Developer"
        },
    },
    "data" :     {
//Your data comes here
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you are using a deprecated delegate method. You could try to use the new delegate methods.

```
@available(iOS, introduced: 3.0, deprecated: 10.0, message: "Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:] or -[UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:] for user visible notifications and -[UIApplicationDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:] for silent remote notifications")
optional public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any])
```